# Carriage Return converted into symbol ( Vertical Tab, male symbol, symbol for Mars ) by PowerPoint Text shape Object in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I have assigned string having carriage return to PowerPoint shape's texframe text but when I get from it. the carriage return is now Ascii 11 VT. I have searched google but I didn't find any solution exception to use linefeed but that does not work in other scenario.

Here is Code

```
_answerText = "Yes" + Chr(CharCode:=13) + "No"
powerPointShapeObject.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _answerText
```

Could some one please help me to understand why it happen. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You shouldn't use the + operator to concatenate strings.  It may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: i used ampersand sign but that also doesn't work

Comment: @SamMakin - As long as you have Option Strict On (which you should) then there are no unexpected results using `+`

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint uses different characters for line endings depending on PPT version and on whether the text is part of a slide title or any other text on a slide.

This page on my PPTFAQ site explains in more detail:

Paragraph endings and line breaks
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
_answerText = "Yes" & "\r" & "No"
powerPointShapeObject.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _answerText
```

Comment: this doesn't work in vb rather we use VBCR but that is main problem carriage return work until it is not assigned to shape object when i assign it to shape then from shape I get symbol instead CR